# usage limits of directionsService.route

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created different routes based on address. Currently I have about 36 different route defined by a start and end position. 3 days ago it was working. My page is on local PC and I will not use on web. This is the code in javascript:

```
    function RedZones(RedZone){
            if (RedZone.checked == true){

    for (var k=0; k < NumeroIndirizziRossi; k++){
            calcRoute(IndirizziRossi[k], IndirizziRossi[k+1]);
            k++;
            }
            }
    else{
    if (directionsDisplayArray) {
                            for (i in directionsDisplayArray) {

                                    directionsDisplayArray[i].setMap(null);
                            }
                                    directionsDisplayArray.length = 0;
                    }


    }
    }

       function calcRoute(source,destination){

    var request = {
        origin:source, 
        destination:destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) 
    {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
        {   

        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplayArray.push(directionsDisplay);               
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);             
        }
    });
  }
```

Now I get a google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT after the first 10 requests. The problem is that I haven't change anything. I have controlled the [usage limits](http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits) and I have created a delay of 2 seconds every 10 requests as the documentation shows, but is not enough. The delay required  is 10 seconds every 10 requests (based on empirical tests), that is not sustainable. Why this problem? Have Google changed the usage limit? I have tried to use the Google Maps API, but the result is the same.

Comment: Your application sounds like it might not comply with the Terms of Use.  Perhaps google is enforcing tighter quotas to prevent abuse.

Comment: Why does not my application comply with the Terms of Use? The usage limit is 10 requests per seconds not 10 requests per 10 seconds.

Comment: <https://developers.google.com/maps/terms> You said "My page is on local PC and I will not use on web." That (at least in my opinion, IANAL) violates this: (b) Public Access (No Firewall). Your Maps API implementation must not operate (i) only behind a firewall; or (ii) only on an internal network (except during the development and testing phase); or (iii) in a closed community (for example, through invitation-only access).

Comment: I use it on local page because is a project for the university. I'm in the development and testing phase.

Comment: Sorry then. The "I will not use on web" lead me to believe you were not planning on deploying it externally.  That could also be the reason that the quotas have changed (to prevent people from abusing the system).

Comment: Hi, did you by any chance find a solution to this or what is causing it, cause i'm having the same problem